# how to unsubscribe from from live rssbook-marks in firefox

Tags: firefox

I want to see [this page](http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2502265) but I always see this alert :
[image]

and I'm unable to see the page please tell me how to get rid of that ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Tools>Options>Applications and see there might be this

[image]

Simply change this to this:

[image]